# HTML form with two submit buttons and two different actions

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, button

I have this form, with 2 submit buttons:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="send_mail(this);return false">

    <select name="liste">
     <option value='0'>Choose list</option>
     <option value="1">list1</options>
         <option value="2">list2</options>      
    </select>

<p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />

<div id="editor">
<textarea value="editor1" name="editor1">Some text here</textarea>
</div>

 <input type="submit" value="Sent Mail!" />
 <div id="testmail">
     <p><input type="button" onsubmit="send_Testmail(this);return false" value="Sent Test" />
     To: <input type="text" name="testemail" /><br />
</div>
</form>
```

On the form, as you can see, it has this javascript function: `onsubmit="send_mail(this);return false`

Which looks like this:

```
function send_mail(form) {
   jQuery.post('editor.php', jQuery(form).serialize(), function(data) {
   jQuery('#center').html(data);
});
    }
```

The script sends the form data to my editor.php script, which processes and send the mail, and then returns "email send". The scripts replaces the `<div>` with the `<form>`, with this `return` statement. This is working as I wanted it to.

Now I want to create another button and input textbox to let the user type in an email and send a test of the above form, before submitting it.

How can I do this? The problem is that the 2 button always submits the javascript send_mail, since its attached to the form tag `onsubmit`.

This is probably a basic question - I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

To clarify: The first button should send $post to my editor.php file and the javascript replaces the  div that holds the entire form. My Second button should send $post to my testmail.php file and only replace the div that holds this button and input textfield (the  with ID "testmail".

Hope that makes sense.. and thanks a lot for the help so fare.

Comment: i find your approach overcomplicated ,anyway you can change your form action on click of button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript is not the best. You shouldn't be using it inline like you are (e.g. with the `onsubmit` attribute). Instead, it should be unobtrusive so your form should work even if JavaScript is not enabled in the user's browser. An example of which:

```
<form action="editor.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
  <div>
    <label for="to">To:</label>
    <input type="text" name="to" id="to" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
            var action = $(this).attr('action');
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.post(action, data, function(response) {
                $('#response').html(response);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above will see your form still submit to **editor.php** if JavaScript is not available, but if JavaScript *is* available, then the JavaScript block will pick up for the form submission, and instead post it using AJAX rather than redirect to **editor.php**.

If you're wanting to also send test emails, I'd include a checkbox instead with the name `test`, and if it's checked change the logic in your form handler (in this case **editor.php**) rather than having an entirely different script. At the simplest, it would look like this:

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    // do something
    // maybe set $to to something different
}

if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
    echo 'Sent';
}
else {
    echo 'Not sent';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will clean that up :)
But how about when I want 2 buttons, one who submits to editor.php and the other to testmail.php ?

Comment: Did you read the last sentence, beginning 'If you're wanting to also send test emails…'?

Comment: Thanks lot, please read the update to my first post. Maybe I can implement your logic, with some simple changes to my javascript/jquery. Im javascript beginner

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I'm just suggesting a more sensible approach, rather than two submit buttons that send the form to two different scripts. You should use the same script and change the logic depending on whether someone's checked 'test' or not.

Comment: I Know and thanks a lot for the suggestion. Its just that I really need it to use a different php file for each button, and a different javascript for each button - for it to work like I want. As you can see it is changing the content of a different div, depending on which button you click. Thats essential for my question.

Comment: I think you need to look at basic control structures, like `if` statements. They'll help you immensely so you're not having to write different JavaScript and PHP code to handle one tiny difference in your scripts.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, just wanted to thank you for all the help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to make an ajax post and submit the form. **Do either one.**

Have 2 normal buttons and do whatever you want via `S.post`.

```
<form>
 <div id="testmail">
     <p><input type="button" onsubmit="send_Testmail(this);return false" value="Sent Test" />
     To: <input type="text" name="testemail" /><br />
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Send Mail!" />
</form>

$('#button1").click(function(form) {
   $.post('editor.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
   $('#center').html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Its because I have omitted some stuff that is not relevant to the question. But could I move the onclick events down on the buttons instead? Say I want the first button to send $Post to editor.php and the other button send $Post to testmail.php.. Having a hard time to get it to work :/

Comment: That should work.. You just need to repeat what I have done for `button2`. Do not "submit" the form. Are you getting any other errors in your console? What's not working?

Comment: If I move the onclick events down on the submit buttons instead of the form tags, my jquery script does not work or none of the $post parameters gets send. It simply reloads the page. Echo'en stuff out from testmail.php or editor.php tells me it does not receive any form info.

I really need this to work with a different php file for each button, to fit my program.

Comment: @That's because you've used **submit** buttons. Use a normal ones(like in the answer). Submit buttons will do a postback.